# angular:6 typescript:2 primeng:7 cause "cli Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts"

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, primeng

Hello I use `"@angular/core": "6.1.7"` and  `"typescript": "^2.9.2"` with `"@angular/cli": "^6.2.1"`.

But my `"primeng": "^7.0.0-beta.1"` show this error

> ERROR in node_modules/primeng/components/picklist/picklist.d.ts(65,28): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.

eg: `export declare const value = 1;`

This is illegal in TypeScript 2.0 but became legal in TypeScript 2.1 with the introduction of literal type inference for const declarations.

I have already a typescript version >2.1 and  can't up my typescript to 3.x because CLI need typescript under 3.x

P.S. I removed each time node_module and cache clean.

**update from anwser**: I choose option a) from Downgrade the primeng versión to 6.1.x to match your current angular core version

Comment: You probably can solve this by downgrading the PrimeNG version, or update the Angular core version to the latest one, you should be using the Angular 7.x version in order to work with PrimeNg 7.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to work, the angular core version and the primeNg version must match. So you have two options:

a) Update the `@angular/core` version to 7.1

b) Downgrade the `primeng` versión to 6.1.x to match your current angular core version

Then remove the node_modules, clean the cache and `npm install`

Comment: I need promeng latest version i.e primeng 7 or lates.

Comment: @SrikrushnaPal can you please explain yourself better? If you need the latest version of primeNG then, as I said, update the angular core and deps to the latest version ( or at least the newest that match with primeng ). In the primeng web page you'll have for sure the angular version that match for each primeng version.